# How to obtain PDF size in LaTeX--70x60mm

Tags: geometry

I have to obtain PDF size 70 x 60 mm. How to obtain these sizes?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. If Heiko's answer solved your problem, please consider accepting his answer by clicking the checkmark icon on the left.

Comment: @close voter: it's clear that the question is what HO answers :-)

Answer (score 3):

For example, package `geometry` can set the paper size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=70mm, paperheight=60mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PhilippImhof Thanks for the welcome :-) (You might want to move your comment to the question?)

Comment: Ha ha :-) it was meant to be a comment on the comment,  of course. So I thought this would be the better place to add it. I moved it now.